# left it to us, as a basic exercise, to V

Tags: pronouns, dummy-pronouns

I'd like to know if the pronoun "it" can be dropped in the following. What'd be the correct analysis?

> The teacher left **it** to us, as a basic exercise, to sort the balls into different colors.

> The teacher left **it** to us to sort the balls into different colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can remove it.  As an American speaker I like to include it, and I feel a slight pressure if I remove it to replace it by saying "left to us the task of sorting" the balls.

You're astute to notice the slight oddness of the formulation.  Perhaps it would be considered idiomatic, the phrase "leave it to X"  - or really just "leave it"... (I might say, for example, "I left it for another time to tidy up", and I think most Americans would, to the point that some would not even be confident you could remove the "it".)  I think it is a little safeguard that can sometimes make it easier to follow speech, and we've gotten used to it.  It sounds a little more British to me, or at least more formal, when removed.

Comment: Yes, I noticed the version without "it" while reading Frankenstein: _They had left to us, as an easier task, to give new names, and arrange in connected classifications, the facts which they in a great degree had been the instruments of bringing to light._